# CodeIgniter form_submit and aJax use to create data table

Tags: php, ajax, forms, codeigniter, submit

How it is possible to create system like:
In form I have 2 inputs ("Date from" and "Date to") and after click on "Submit" button, table with data(which was collected by using database query in which Dates were set). I made everything in PHP, everything works, but I have no idea, how to implement aJax for it. The point why I need aJax is that table must apear in same page, after submition of Date (I also  set default date(todays date), there is no need to set Date).

I think, there my code is necessary, but if there is need, please ask, I will give it. 
So, question is, how is it possible to implement aJax there?

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery you could do something like this

PHP generate_table.php

```
<?php
    $start_date = $_POST['start_date'];
    $end_date = $_POST['end_date'];
    //Here goes your table generation script
    $table = sprintf('<p>%s - %s</p>',$start_date,$end_date); //Generated table (here's just a p for simplicity
    echo json_encode(array('table' => $table));     
?>
```

HTML index.html

```
<form id="dates">
    <input name="start_date" />
    <input name="end_date" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit_date" />
</form>

<div id="generated_table"></div>

<script>
    //We generate the event when they click the submit button
    $('#submit_date').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();//Prevent default behaviour
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'generate_table.php',
            data:$('#dates').serialize(), //Sending the dates as post parameters
            success:function(data){
                $('#generated_table').html(data.table); //Output the table in the div
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```